# JetBrains Rider adds label/bubble with parameter name into functions, how do I remove it?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I started using JetBrains Rider and it adds strange "value" bubble/label into functions that I don't need.

How do I remove it?

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [parameter name hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html). Hints in *C#* and *VB.NET* can be configured under **Editor | Parameter Name Hints**.
Hints in *JavaScript, TypeScript,* and *SQL* can be configured on the **Editor | General | Appearance** settings page.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/11/27/inline-parameter-name-hints-c-vb-net-resharper-rider/